# How to add frame box to all pages where a section is located?

Tags: pdftex

I have a special need now. Look at the picture in detail. The gray line is paper, and the black line box is the one I want to add. I require the section to be outside and all the contents in this section to be framed. The number of pages is uncertain. It is required to be able to frame the newly added pages as the content increases. Other pages are normal. Such as front and back. When I say there are other normal pages, I mean I can't frame all pages without thinking.

I tried `fancybox.sty`, but it couldn't meet my needs. I'm thinking of using tikz. I can frame some pages, but I can't automatically detect the number of pages and frame each page. I don't know if I have expressed my needs clearly.

[image]

Comment: If the section content is not too complex, wrapping it in a breakable `tcolorbox` worth a try.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you very much for your prompt. I used `tcolorbox` to finish my typesetting.

Comment: How would you manage floats?

Comment: @Werner There are no figures and tables in my requirements, and there is no need to consider the floating problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @muzimuzhiZ, I used `tcolorbox` to finish my typesetting.

```latex
\newcommand\boxmargin{5pt}
\newcommand\boxrule{1pt}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
  standard jigsaw,
  sharp corners=all,
  colframe=red,
  breakable,
  height fixed for=all,
  height fill=maximum,
  opacityback=0,
  boxsep=0pt,
  boxrule=\boxrule,
  top=\boxmargin,
  bottom=\boxmargin,
  left=\boxmargin,
  right=\boxmargin,
  space to upper,
  lower separated=false,
  halign lower=flush right,
  before upper={\parindent 2em \linespread{1}\fontsize{12}{20}\selectfont},
}
```

The above is the configuration of my box, hoping to help people with similar needs.